# JavaCard ARQC and ICC MK Retrieve

Tags: java, javacard, emv, jcop

I'm a member of a finance and security startup in Brazil and need some help to keep my projects.

Is possible to retrieve ICC Master key from card with any kind of software or even hardware?

I have ARQC calculated and other variables used to calculate ARQC but don't have a session key. Is it possible to somehow find it?

```
9F26 Application Cryptogram
    0F18620281900928
9F27 Cryptogram Information Data
    80
9F10 Issuer Application Data
    0210A50003020000DD8800000000
9F37 Unpredictable Number
    426243DB
9F36 Application Transaction Counter (ATC)
    0018
95 Terminal Verification Results
    0000008000
9A Transaction Date
    121229
9C Transaction Type
    00
9F02 Amount, Authorised (Numeric)
    000000020300
5F2A Transaction Currency Code
    0986
82 Application Interchange Profile
    5800
9F1A Terminal Country Code
    0076
9F03 Amount, Other (Numeric)
    000000000000
9F34 Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results
    410302
5F34 Application Primary Account Number (PAN) Sequence Number
```

Comment: It is not possible, unless you crack it, but it is not easy, and it is not permitted by the law.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible and would be defeating the purpose :)

It's extremely rare that you would actually need to do this for legitimate purposes, though. The only thing I can think of is testing of card and authorization systems during development. In those case you typically get cards with test keying material either the from bank, card- or test equipment vendor with known keys.

Why do you want to do this anyway? Perhaps there's an easier way to reach your goal.